# Create javascript array from ajax string . 

Tags: javascript, servlets

```
var  data = [
        {lastName: "Dente", name: "Al"},
        {lastName: "Noring", name: "Constance"},
        {lastName: "Haas", name: "Jack"},
        {lastName: "Tress", name: "Matt"},
        {lastName: "Turner", name: "Paige"}
    ];
```

this is the javascript array i want to create. How to send this data from a servlet and create the array object in javascript.

```
String dataString=/*prepare data */
response.getWriter().write(dataString);
```

How to prepare this dataString in servlet and how to create array from that string in the client ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the following Java class:

```
public class Person {
    private String lastName;
    private String name;

    public Person(String lastName, String name) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.name = name;
    }

    /* getters and setters */
}
```

Then you can easily generate the data via the following using [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/):

```
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

people.add(new Person("Smith", "John"));
people.add(new Person("Example", "An"));

String json = gson.toJson(people);
```

The `json` variable will then have a value of `[{"lastName": "Smith", "name": "John"},{"lastName": "Example", "name": "An"}]`.

Then just send that as the response from your servlet, remember to set the content type of the request to `application/json`.

In order to get a handle on the data in JavaScript I would recommended using jQuery's [.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method, e.g.

```
$.getJSON('url of servlet', function (data) {
    console.log(data); // <-- data will be an Array containing two objects
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation.
after getting data from server, how can i create the array ?? this is what i actually need.

is it correct to declare like this??

var data=dataStringFromServer;

Comment: If you use the code in my example the `data` variable in the callback `function` of the `$.getJSON` call with already be an Array. Are you currently getting the data back from the server in JSON format?

Comment: at present i am not using the jquery function. i am using the plain XMLHttp request. But i am getting the json string. So, i want to create the array object from that string. except that all i have done is same as you said.

Comment: OK, no problem. If you're using plain XHR you can just use `var data = JSON.parse(str);` where `str` is the data that was returned from your servlet. In order to ensure `JSON.parse` works in older browsers make sure you include the [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) file in your page.

Answer (score 1):

Use `net.sf.json.JSONObject` to achieve this in serverside

Serverside:

```
public class Data {
    String lastName;
    String name;
//......constructors,getters,setters
}

ArrayList<Data> serverData = new ArrayList<Data>();
serverData.add(new Data("Fred", "Flintstones"));
serverData.add(new Data("Wilma", "Flintstones"));
String jsonStr = JSONObject.fromObject(serverData);
response.getWriter().write(jsonStr);
```

Use `JSON.parse` in client side

Client side:

```
function ajaxCallback(data) {
    var jObj = JSON.parse(data);
    for(var i in jsonObject)
    {alert(jObj[i].name+" "+jObj[i].lastName);}
}
```

Hope this helps!